# How regex until last occurrence?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python, I need regex to get contacts link of web page. So, I made `<a (.*?)>(.*?)Contacts(.*?)</a>` and result is:

```
href="/ru/o-nas.html"  id="menu263" title="About">About</a></li><li><a href="/ru/photogallery.html" id="menu645" title="Photo">Photo</a></li><li  class="last"><a href="/ru/kontakt.html" class="last" id="menu583" title="">Contacts
```

,but I need on last `<a ...` like

```
href="/ru/kontakt.html" class="last" id="menu583" title="">Contacts
```

**What regex pattern should I use?**

python code:

```
match = re.findall('<a (.*?)>(.*?)Contacts(.*?)</a>', body)
if match:
    for m in match:
        print ''.join(m)
```

Comment: Why not use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: are you forgetting escape...<a(.*?)>(.*?)Contacts(.*?)<\/a>

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara: A forward slash is not a special regex character, and does not need escaping.

Comment: What is the real expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are parsing HTML, I would suggest to use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
# sample html from question
html = '<li><a href="/ru/o-nas.html"  id="menu263" title="About">About</a></li><li><a href="/ru/photogallery.html" id="menu645" title="Photo">Photo</a></li><li  class="last"><a href="/ru/kontakt.html" class="last" id="menu583" title="">Contacts</a></li>'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(html)
aTag = doc.find('a', id='menu583') # id for Contacts link
print(aTag['href'])
# '/ru/kontakt.html'
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I can not use id param, because I need parse a lot of web sites. one way is to find by word `Contacts`

Comment: Yes, you can find the node by searching for what it contains e.g. Contacts in your case.

Comment: `text='Contacts'` works! What if I need find `a` that contains one of the word from list?

Comment: @sirjay in case of a list, you can simply use `soup.find('a', text=['text1', 'text2'])`.

Comment: @sirjay: If you look at the documentation, you can find multiple features, such as using Regex, using a Function etc. in `text` or `string` (for newer version) fields. This provides you a lot of flexibility on how you want to filter the elements.

Comment: Ok, found it! One last question: can I find by 2 params with logic 'or'? Example: `soup.find('a', text='Contacts' ..or.. href='/contacts')`

Comment: To write complex queries, you can build your filters in a [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

Answer (score 0):

Try BeautifulSoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
links = []
urls  ['www.u1.com','www.u2.om'....]
for url in urls:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        if link.string.lower() == 'contact':
            links.append(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: modified as per requirements

Comment: Note that you are using `BeautifulSoup` version 3 which is not developed and maintained